# How to reference type of self in Typescript interface (for a IClonable interface)

Tags: typescript

I need an `IClonable` interface that defines a `clone()` member, that returns an instance of the class that implemented it.

If possible, how can I indicate that the return type of `clone()` will be the same as the class it is called on?

```
interface IClonable {
    clone(): ???
}
```

I know I can do this with generics like below, but that seems overly verbose

```
interface IClonable<T> {
    clone(): T
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Update Oct 11th, 2022

**The previous answer had a flaw that only shows up when the inheritance chain grows beyond our simple example. Consider this example:**

```
class B extends A {
  foo() {
    console.log("Foobar");
  }
}

const b = new B(3).clone() // type: B ???
b.foo(); // RuntimeError: b.foo is not a function
```

[*Playground link*](https://tsplay.dev/WzP5QN)

There is a problem here that won't be caught at compile time, and only during runtime will we see it. Therefore, I propose *yet* another alternative:

##### Solution

```
interface ICloneable {
    clone(): ThisType<this>;
}

class A implements ICloneable {
  constructor(readonly a: number){}

  clone() {
    return new A(this.a);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
const a = new A(42).clone(); // type: A

class B extends A {
  foo() {
    console.log("Foobar");
  }
}

const b = new B(3).clone() // type: A

// @ts-expect-error
b.foo();
```

By using a [contextualized `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) type, the return type for `clone` is bound to the context within which it was declared, and not the context within which it was called.

Now if we remove the `// @ts-expect-error` comment, typescript will catch this error at runtime, because the clone method we have in `B` does not return type `B`.

---

#### Previous answer:

Use (polymorphic) [`this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) as the return type:

```
interface ICloneable {
    clone(): this;
}
```

> In classes, a special type called `this` refers dynamically to the type of the current class.

Usage:

```
class A implements ICloneable {
  constructor(readonly a: number){}

  clone() {
    return new A(this.a) as this;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's very interesting, is this a relatively new feature of typescript?

Comment: @altschuler I don't think so. The link I have there explains what it is, but it does not say what version of typescript introduced it. I will update the answer if I find a link that gives more information

Comment: @altschuler, well I couldn't find anything, but as of 2015, there was already an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6223) addressing this feature, so I'm guessing it has always either been a part of typescript or introduced pretty early into the language. Furthermore, as of the end of 2015 the [latest release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript#Release_history) was version 1.7.

Comment: ```
class A { hooks: { add: SyncHook<[??]>; } }
```
What if there is a subclass extends A, the ?? part should be subclass too so I can not place A in there. How to solve this? you can't use this in there.

Comment: @towry that's an interesting question. I tried doing something [similar](http://www.staging-typescript.org/play?target=2&jsx=0&ts=3.9.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQE4FMwBMD2AdiAJ7QAWeeA1hAFzQASlNAPAC5kCWEAfANxIUaYIQht0AV2Bs86ABQBKRELRo2xAA6ZoAFWgBeaB24DVqlWeMQAdBWoxDyM8+i4c9Jy68RiBYHIhMEAAzeh0lTy8o6BECCDwQTGsQPABzAKDg62DKRQVTaLMAXwsvErKLEoscvEVlL1j4xOS0uQAiWDaFSqQq0EgYACFoTAAPNkwCHBh4SOgaurnVRoSklPS2wa6evvAoaABhRGgqzgIJ9GCwYG0AZV9gJmoWHR56tB8-AH56DJCwpT6N4ANzwnBwvUEZwuVxujGYEBebzmbno9z8TyoSMhSEabGgACMDNACJgAO7QQaKJAE2wI6xuayfYAAQhZclJFNgeSAA), but it didn't work. Ask a new question and link here

Comment: @smac89  [PlaygroundLink](http://www.staging-typescript.org/play?target=2&jsx=0&ts=3.9.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQJ4DsDGAJCEDWcAvnAGZQQhwBEMAhmHQEYA2AptQNwBQ3w6MNlFJ1MbOLgIBnADwAVAHyJucVXClsWpAFwoMOPPnkKeRXphZ0pUuADU2AMWhUEKtQAtDU3ZPyyY7sBSJrxqcJgQ6FIwUACumDDQABQAlMphYQFBAHSe0nAAvOkZJRpauuhsAO56WL5JANrUpM7UALopbiVmYWZdcPzAMKnFJVlSuV7ZZaTZmHQsLEnjKTy93H0WVjYAwrHRlPZOUFRsAB6C6AAmNkfOo3CC0SOuJaoRURDs2SwQAOZJWhsaLUVb9MybSLRMj3IqVGp7A4gO4nVI8FonSbSaaaWb0MCAgAKLFif34ADk6CAOAAaOBJDEgNIFJSvNSM7JPYZgoidbgcwbczhAA)
 It seems this will work. use interface with generic, pass this to interface.

Comment: @towry I wasn't sure if it will work for you because the last line calls the function using `A` instead of `B` and it works, but I don't think that should have worked. If you are ok with that, I guess that's fine

Comment: Yeah, this works: https://github.com/towry/n/issues/138#issuecomment-640164288

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. See [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBsD2IJwEbooDeAUMsgljgBQCUAXMmABbADOJAviSZXG22QBBZMAC2AB0JiI4QRmy4CxMhWxswUAK4IwmKNSi4AJtnQBPZHEYgtYvNFpFuqyorqMRpcuSNgtUCDIOADuwtQs7AB0cLSq3JxAA)

Comment: @deamon yea, it seems the typescript team is having difficulties implementing this feature properly, and they had to revert a bunch of their code that used it because of performance issues with the compiler. I updated my answer showing a different approach

Answer (score 4):

You are right, using generics is the way to do it, even if it's verbose..

You can also:

```
interface IClonable {
    clone(): any;
}
```

or

```
interface IClonable {
    clone(): any;
    clone<T>(): T;
}
```

or

```
interface IClonable {
    clone(): IClonable;
}
```

But using generics is probably the best way to go.

---

#### Edit

@Silvermind comments below made me check the suggested code of `clone<T>(): T` and I was wrong as it does not compile.
First Here's a code to show what I meant:

```
class Point implements IClonable {
    private x: number;
    private y: number;
    
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public clone<T>(): T {
        return <T> new Point(this.x, this.y);
    }
}

var p1 = new Point(1, 2);
var p3 = p1.clone<Point>();
```

Basically to perform the cast in the `clone` method instead of casting the returned value.
But `<T> new Point(this.x, this.y)` produces:

> Neither type 'Point` nor type 'T' is assignable to each other

Comment: Do you know if this is the case in "all" OOP languages or is the ability to reference the "type of this" available elsewhere?

Comment: @altschuler I edited my answer with another option, but it won't make it more comfortable.  As far as I'm aware this is the same in all OO, as you don't have access to `this` in the method signatures or class definitions. You don't know who will later implement `IClonable` so how would you know to return that type? What if 10 different classes implement it?  That's what the generics are for

Comment: Why do you suggest `clone<T>`? That would be really hard to clone to :)

Comment: @Silvermind it's kinda like casting. instead of `let o: MyType = <MyType> obj.clone()` you do `let o: MyType = obj.clone<MyType>()`

Comment: @NitzanTomer I know, but if the requestor can specify the type, than it is virtually impossible to for the implementor to meet the callers requirements. How would the implementor know which properties exist on T?

Comment: @Silvermind Well, it's an interface so there's no implementation...  later when you implement it in a specific class you know exactly what to return.

Comment: No you don't because the interface forces you to implement `clone<T>(): T` so the type is still not known in the implementation. I think you meant `clone(): T`, where T is from `IClonable<T>`.