# Why Typescript interfaces allow self references?

Tags: typescript, types

```
type SomeGeneric<T> = {
    x: T;
}

type TTest = SomeGeneric<TTest> & { a: string; }; // Type alias 'TTest' circularly references itself.

interface ITest extends SomeGeneric<ITest> { // OK
    a: string;
}
```

I fail to understand why interfaces are allowed to reference themselves in their own declarations and types aren't.

Comment: How else do you suggest implementing a [“cloneable” interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36744033/1968), say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type aliases can't be recursive (mostly), while interfaces can. If you search GitHub there are several answers given as to why.

For example RyanCavanaugh explains [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14174#issuecomment-307892442):

> Type aliases and interfaces are subtly different and there are rules about self-recursion for aliases that don't apply to interfaces. Because an alias is supposed to always be "immediately expandable" (it's as if it were an in-place expansion of its referand), there are things you can do interfaces you can't do with type aliases.

Or [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12525#issuecomment-263166239) by DanielRosenwasser

> The restriction that a type alias can't be referenced by itself at the top level has been the behavior since we implemented type aliases; however, you might recall that a while back, we started allowing type aliases to be referenced from within an object type. 
>   ...
>   However, it has no problem provided that the type can be expanded, or "unrolled" one level at a time. In other words, as long as you have some sort of box-y thing containing the type:

The general workaround is to use an interface if you want a recursive type.

Just as a side note, the rules are not exactly enforced consistently. For example while in your case `SomeGeneric<TTest>` could be expanded to `{ x: TTest }` the compiler does not even attempt it, it just fails. The following recursive definition will however work:

```
type TTest = { x: TTest } & { a: string; };
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it works for `extends` is because you basically *extend* the interface by one more field and that is the interface itself. e.g.

```
private x: ITest; // is fine
private a: string;
```

By trying to declare a type referencing itself will result in an endless reference loop. That's why it does not work.