# Flow to TypeScript migration

Tags: typescript, flowtype

I try to migrate a project that i haven't written from Flow to TypeScript.
I have some Flow structure for which i can not find a equivalent in TypeScript.

```
type Value =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | BaseObject
  | Array<BaseObject>

type BaseObject = ObjectMap<?Value> & {
  meta?: BaseObject;
}

type ObjectMap<T> = {
  [key: string]: T;
};
```

I got this errors : `Type alias 'BaseObject' circularly references itself` and `Type alias 'Value' circularly references itself`. I understand what this error means but i can't find a way to get the same behavior without error in TS.

any idea?

Comment: Could you please post the flow structure that you are trying to replicate.

Comment: Wht do you means? I posted the code that cause the error.

Comment: Is that the TypeScript code, the Flow code, or both? It would be helpful to see the Flow code that you are trying to replicate, and the TypeScript code that you have attempted.

Comment: It's the Flow Code. i just try to make it compile with tsc.

Comment: The Flow code does not pass type check here in the Flow playground https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLwCgpQD5QM7ABOAlgHYDmmOUpSAtgEYSFW4MD27CEcprUAITh4IAeQYArCAGNg-AIKFCcEAB4hI8VNkA+dOjLBmAMzjToGsZJnAoEAB5HSAEzxRFytfGQQdUVFBaNgCycGCq3ijUtAgI1EguEMZkEM5+AGRQAN5UdBDAcAD8AFyCwlbawADc6AC++qCQgdayoeEAKn4BOVgA2gDWECClBCQUALql7TW1VUA Are you sure it's valid Flow code?

Comment: Uhm yeah sorry. I have already adapted some part. I update my question with the original code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [TypeScript in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBUAsFNQVwHYGNIEMEHNoBNQDEAbAewHdQAXATwAdYSiAnAawGdQBLBCG6AZSQbtq5AHQBYAFBVaoAGqoCcWAF5JodaAA+oFuUGY1G7QjgBbAEbQGh9dvNEiBaOhtbQAIVQtoAeXMAraCRyV20AQQYGVEoAHk9vP0DggD5JSRAIGHhkNEwcfGIyaTpGVg4ucB5+QWFxKR5QRKDyAFlUahjwZNBlUABvVwBtJmhKAC4dPU4MAF0J8ABuSQBfJYl0sChYRBR0LFxCUgoeEVON45l43wDmnsab4LaOgH55RWhugDJ+841QU2g5FQzwmVyawTWGWWaQkGVOInQuHIWWgAEc4OwAG4KaAIcjcWjVISiSScchWABmqCQsDBD3x0AAHuSENg2ODWu0Ym8lG4TAQCG5ENhoBTODhugMJH8AUCQR4vNckuQ1tD1rCwAARaCmIiSJBEBC6UCM0GKjl3KV-agMIjUACME35BAANK4bXaAEwTYWi8XYN3SjQe6gAZgmAHIQ6GI4HrbbqAAWCb2gAMceDCYArBMrX8NLLULm1X9lhn1CGAGwTQZ5-P-QFF-oljTLGbl0AhgDsTugZE1qHJAAoAJSgDJIVBwbxsdCgKy26wSNVAA) (and the equivalent [Flow in the playground](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLwCgpagHygZ2ACcBLAOwHNNs8ykBbAIwiOqz0YHtOEI4y2uKACE4+CAHlGAKwgBjYILwBBIkTggAPKPFTZCgHzp0oSCLGSZ84FFRQ91gLJwwmgPzxkEA1ABkUAG9BeghgODcALnNdKwUAbnQAX2NTaAcFZ1cAFR87IOwoAG0AawgQKMJSSgBdKKyExITjdCA)).

```
// The unchanged Flow type works in TypeScript.
type Value =
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | BaseObject
    | Array<BaseObject>

// The unchanged Flow type works in TypeScript.
type ObjectMap<T> = {
    [key: string]: T;
};

// The unchanged Flow type...
// type BaseObject = ObjectMap<?Value> & {
//     meta?: BaseObject;
// }

// ...and the equivalent TypeScript.
interface BaseObject extends ObjectMap<Value | null | undefined> {
    meta?: BaseObject;
}
```

Some notes on the differences:

- Flow's `?Value` is a [`Maybe`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/); the TypeScript equivalent is `Value | undefined | null`.
- Flow's `type` may self-reference/recurse; in TypeScript [an interface may self-reference/recurse but a type usually may not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53279416/1108891).

Demo

```
const x: BaseObject = {
    prop1: null,
    prop2: undefined,
    prop3: 'prop3',
    prop4: 10,
    prop5: {
        meta: {}
    },
    prop6: [{
        meta: {}
    }],
    prop7: new Date() // causes an error
}
```

Comment: Slight improvement: replace `ObjectMap<Value>` with `Record<string, Value>`. No need to introduce an extra type for that.