# Interface type variable / generic variable to refer to current class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

It's often the case that I want to refer to the implementing class in the interface definition, e.g.

```
interface Clonable<T> {
   clone() : T;
}
```

And a class that implements this would look like

```
class C implements Clonable<C> {
   clone() : C {
      // do something and return a new C object
   }
}
```

This is *good enough* but it irks me that the use of generic variable `T` conveys a broader meaning than I wish. I.e. it's possible to implement this wrongly like:

```
class C implements Clonable<B> {
   clone() : B {
      // actually returns a new B and not a new C. Violates interface author's intention but still typechecks!
   }
}
```

That's the issue: the generic param `T` is too broad and could be used wrongly while still typechecking.

Is there another variable that just refers to the implementing class? Or a way to restrict T to only that?

Comment: I donot think this is what you want, but this narrows it to some extent `interface Clonable<T extends Clonable<T>>`

Comment: Closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/36744033/1412255  . There doesn't seem to be a way of doing what I want, but the linked answer contains links to other discussions about this feature, some of them on typescript repo issues