# Self reference key type in a TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript, interface

I have an object with the following interface that I would like to update programatically:

```
interface ITypes {
  num: number;
  str: string;
  bol: boolean;
};

const obj: Partial<ITypes> = {}; // I want to update this programatically
```

I want to be able to define a `key` and a `val` and update my `obj` using those values. I want it so that the `key` can only be one of the keys from the `ITypes` interface, and the value would then be need to be the type specified at the selected `key` from the interface. I can do this just fine using the below code:

```
const key: keyof ITypes = "num"; // key must be a key from the ITypes interface
const val: ITypes[typeof key] = 1; // val must be the type specified at `"num"` - `number`
obj[key] = val;
```

The above code works fine, however, now, instead of having `key` and `val` as seperate variables, I want to define them in an object, and so I need to define an interface. However, I'm having trouble with the type definition for `val`. This is what I have tried so far:

```
interface IUpdatePayload {
  key: keyof ITypes;
  val: ITypes[typeof this.key]; // Type 'any' cannot be used as an index type.
};
const updatePayload: IUpdatePayload = {key: "num", val: "1"}; // should complain that `val` is not a number
obj[updatePayload.key] = updatePayload.val;
```

I've tried to self-reference the interface's `key` type using `typeof this.key` (which I saw suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57767027/5648954)) however that is erroring with `Type 'any' cannot be used as an index type.`, I'm guessing it's because key hasn't actually been defined to have a value like in the first working example using variables. My question is, is there a way to make this work so that `val` takes on the type defined by `key` as specified in the `ITypes` interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to generate a union of key/value pairings from any type:

```
type KVPairs<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = 
    K extends keyof T
        ? { key: K, val: T[K] } 
        : never;
```

You can then create your custom union:

```
// {key: "num", val: number} | {key: "str", val: string} | {key: "bol", val: boolean}
type IUpdatePayload = KVPairs<ITypes>;
```

This type also allows you to select a subset of the keys if you want:

```
// {key: "num", val: number} | {key: "str", val: string}
type NumOrStr = KVPairs<ITypes, "num"|"str">
```

However, the error isn't always very clear when assigning object literals to the union type:

```
const obj: IUpdatePayload = { key: "num", val: "1" };
/*
Type '{ key: "num"; val: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IUpdatePayload'.
  Type '{ key: "num"; val: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ key: "bol"; val: boolean; }'.
    Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
      Type '"num"' is not assignable to type '"bol"'.
*/
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUCeAHCBnZAbwFgAoZZEAVwFsAuS2gI2gG4yK8woGupQA5u3LImAewA2DcZIhwQwgL7CyYHCgDSANQAKcYFDwAedABpkG5BAAekEABMCAawiYxMZOmQBeZC7ce6AB8PsgcFBZWthAOzq7unmEiEREA-ER+rgwa5gBucFKeANoaALrIikkpKQwgELlsZKrqaACq2PZwkHqYEmJw9qHaegbGGOp4QSqkCGIgXMhiTABWDKjtnd1wvf2DvoSZmAwARNQ0x3kFJwCMxxXTarjIAHK0APJQAMrcQ7r6hkZxrg8OZTrRjgAfY58Y5TIA)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic interface for this:

```
interface IUpdatePayload<K extends keyof ITypes> {
  key: K;
  val: ITypes[K];
}

const updatePayload: IUpdatePayload<"num"> = {
  key: "num",
  val: "1"
//~~~ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
};
obj[updatePayload.key] = updatePayload.val;
```

The downside of this is you have to specify the generic argument `"num"` (the property that you are updating). To avoid this, you could use a helper function that would allow this argument to be inferred for you:

```
const updateObj = <K extends keyof ITypes>(updatePayload: IUpdatePayload<K>): void => {
  obj[updatePayload.key] = updatePayload.val; 
}
updateObj({key: "num", val: "1"}) // error
updateObj({key: "num", val: 1}) // ok
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUCeAHCBnZAbwChlkQBXAWwC5zqAjaAblOTzCjo6lAHNWZBgHsANnRFiIcEKwC+xYgmEgOyYQwBWdAApwoYYHFEAeDDnwA+ZAF4ic5sgD0TtMgDuMsMjDDkFbAATOEgfAAtgAmwoYT4oOCoQ4ARjUUxFUEhYRBRUAFUgkIg9TFFhOECTAGlkCAAPSBBAggBrCExhGDQsXDxrEjI2zDoqwWQAN2M6c16AbSqAXXlFZVVvAODIErKK6YLN4rhS8sqAIkoqU+s7QiG6c+pTgBoJqeRTgEZTh2dXPDDhBRRIFkMoqNhRHBQOEQsgAAaTURw5CRcjCbxwehUJhQYgaTSzDZFbYnAB0QwWtn8hS2Rx2gVJiNYShUaiJkAA8loqdVag0IE1Wu1Ot0LH0ABTsw7HXZofbEuknaqWACUdHGwmAIJs-TY+MJNOl9PJ7UpdilJIqjOMjmICilXM04tu7XuF2er3E7y+chVxAdWmdd3e7peiLoH19xCAA)