# How do I create a late-binding clone method in TypeScript classes?

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, clone, late-binding

I want to make a simple Cloneable interface for all my data classes, it's easy to do it in JavaScript. But it's not obvious on how to properly type it in TypeScript.

I am currently hacking it together like this:

```js
class BaseClass implements Cloneable {
  clone() {
    return new (this.constructor as any)(this.data);
  }
}
```

I want the `clone` methods of all the sub-classes returns their own type instead of `BaseClass`. For example:

```js
class ExampleSubclass extends BaseClass {}

const foo = new ExampleSubclass();
const bar = foo.clone(); // Expecting `bar` to be `ExampleSubclass`, neither `BaseClass` nor `Cloneable`.
```

Is there a more proper way to do late bindings?

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference type of self in Typescript interface (for a IClonable interface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744033/how-to-reference-type-of-self-in-typescript-interface-for-a-iclonable-interface)

Comment: @smac89 Not exactly. The linked question asks about immediate implementation of an interface, my question is about the inherited subclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should cast it

```
class BaseClass {
  clone() {
    return new (this.constructor as any)(this.data) as typeof this;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer, but `this` is enough as a type without the `typeof` keyword. It works either with or without it though.